# Glitches in inductor current waveform

Tags: voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inductor, buck

I am using this DC-DC [buck converter.](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/switching_regulator/bd9g201efj-m-e.pdf)

Schematics :

[image]

Buck converter specifications :

- Input voltage - 18V to 32V
- Switching frequency - 300kHz
- Output voltage 9V
- Load current - 0mA to 200mA maximum.

When measuring the inductor leak current, I get the following waveform:

[image]

Can someone tell me what causes the glitches circled in red in the inductor peak current waveform?

Comment: Those are probably effects of the half bridge switching. Measure the LX pin to be sure.

Comment: Could be switching noise making it trough the inductor due to stray capacitance.

Comment: Isn't this inductor value a bit too big? According to the datasheet the minimum value should be around \$16\mu H\$ to \$22\mu H\$. The glitch seems to be some noise being coupled by the inductor, or your measurement equipment as the current through the inductor cannot change direction that fast.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Could you please tell me what exactly happens at those peak instants? What would be the current path on the buck converter during that glitching?

Comment: @Newbie you've heard multiple hypotheses there, and they imply reasons. You even got two recommendation what to do to very (Measure at LX, try smaller inductor). You need to investigate yourself based on these - *we* can't know what *your* circuit does.